# How to specify generic cast for Dictionary values while retrieving

Tags: c#, dictionary

This is my code which i wrote as a extension to get value from dictionary with specified cast

```
public static TResult GetValue<TKey, TValue, TResult>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
{
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return default(TResult);
    }

    return dictionary[key] as TResult;
}
```

The error states that,

> Error 1   The type parameter 'TResult' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint

Not able to figure out a way to do this.

I just need to specify the type which i need it as a return type from the method.So i need to cast the dictionary value with this generic type.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use the TryGetValue() method instead of your extension method.

Comment: Why do you need a `TResult` at all? Isn't `TValue` of the desired type?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes right. I will change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler and the users of your APIs that `TResult` will be a name of a reference type, not a name of a value type:

```
public static TResult GetValue<TKey, TValue, TResult>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    where TResult : class {
    ...
}
```

This is required to let you use `as TResult` operator. If you wish to provide similar functionality for value types, add a separate function that takes `TResult` of value type, and return `Nullable<TResult>` instead:

```
public static TResult? GetNullableValue<TKey, TValue, TResult>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    where TResult : struct {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword is valid only on reference types\nullables.
 Use the cast operator or add a `where TResult : class` constrain if you want that restricition.

```
 public static TResult GetValue<TKey, TValue, TResult>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return default(TResult);
        }

        return (TResult)dictionary[key];
    }
```

Comment: That won't result in the same behavior, though. It will fail if the cast is invalid, rather than returning null.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - That's correct - doesn't mean that using as is the correct thing here. It depends if he's using value types or not.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler knows nothing about `TResult`. Try to add `where TResult: class`:

```
public static TResult GetValue<TKey, TValue, TResult>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key
    ) where TResult: class
```

But as **@chglurps* commented, it is better to use `TryGetValue`.